# Passing parameter from url to view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I've noticed something in the mvc default projects that made me wonder how it works. When I create a ddefault MVC Project with Individual User Accounts authentication, visual Studio scaffolds an AccountController with two "ResetPassword" Actions. One that accepts a string parameter via GET request. The Action looks like this:

```
   // GET: /Account/ResetPassword  
    [AllowAnonymous]  
    public ActionResult ResetPassword(string code)  
    {  
        return code == null ? View("Error") : View();  
    }
```

And the View looks like this:

```
@model SISGRAD_MVC.Models.ResetPasswordViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Reset password";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("ResetPassword", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Reset your password.</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Code)
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

I access the Action with the code in the URL, GET-style, and the view knows to initialize the model property from the URL. One point of interest is that this only works if I use `@Html.HiddenFor()`. How does this work, and how does the view know when to pull data from the URL, and when not to?

Comment: If you have a route defined with `Account/ResetPassword/{code}` then you don't even need the hidden input (it will be added to the rote parameters by default)

Comment: All values from route values, query string values and model and added to the `ViewDataDictionary` which is used by the html helper to set the values of associated vales of the form controls

Comment: @StephenMuecke About second commentary, I suspected this too, but a step-by-step in the debugger showed and empty ViewDataDictionary all the way through the view rendering. Besides, why does it only work with Html.HiddenFor()? I tried with DisplayFor and it didn't work.

Comment: I came across a good blog some time ago explaining this better than I could - let me see if I can find it :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke About the first comment, thanks for the tip, but my question is more of a curiosity about the inner workings of the framework, in order to improve my understanding.

Comment: Have not found the article yet (but will have another look later), but the difference with the editor vs display methods is that `@Html.HiddenFor()` will pull the value from `ModelState` - you can see this if you use `<div>@ViewData.ModelState["Code"].Value.AttemptedValue</div>` (because `code` is a parameter of your method, its value is added to `ModelState` by the `DefaultModelBinder`)

Comment: Best way for me to improve my understanding of something is to look at the code. MVC is open source now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you method is

```
public ActionResult ResetPassword(string code)
```

the `DefaultModelBinder` will add the value of `code` to `ModelState`

The `HiddenFor(m => m.Code)` method uses values from `ModelState` rather that the values from the model if they exist so it will render

```
<input type="hidden" name="Code" id="Code" value="###" />
```

where `###` is the value you passed to the method.

Your statement that the *"view knows to initialize the model property from the URL"* is not correct. The model is not initialized and is in fact `null` which you can test using

```
<div>@Model.Code</div>
```

which will throw an *"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."* exception, whereas

```
<div>@ViewData.ModelState["Code"].Value.AttemptedValue</div>
```

will display the correct value.

Side note: From your comments, the reason that `DisplayFor(m => m.Code)` does not show the value is that its is using the value in the `ViewData` (which is `null` because the model is `null`). The default display template uses the following code (refer [source code](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/DefaultDisplayTemplates.cs))

```
internal static string StringTemplate(HtmlHelper html)
{
  return html.Encode(html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue);
}
```

as opposed to `HiddenFor(m => m.Code)` which uses the following code (refer [source code](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/InputExtensions.cs)

```
default:
  string attemptedValue = (string)htmlHelper.GetModelStateValue(fullName, typeof(string));
  tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("value", attemptedValue ?? ((useViewData) ? htmlHelper.EvalString(fullName, format) : valueParameter), isExplicitValue);
  break;
```

Note also that if you define a route with `url: "Account/ResetPassword/{code}"` then you do not need to add the hidden input in your view. It will be added as a route value by default - the `BeginForm()` method will render

```
<form action="Account/ResetPassword/###" ... >
```